Using dynamic_reconfigure witouth the graphical interface
I am learning ROS and I want to use the dynamic_reconfigure to change some parameters on the fly, but I for my project, I can't use the GUI services such as rqt_reconfigure. So I am wondering is there a way to change the parameters without the use of rqt_configure for example with command line?
Thanks

It would be helpful if you stated what version you're using in your question.

You might want to have a look at ros2 cli tool command.
You can use "get" or "set" in the terminal to reconfigure the parameter.
For example:

list all the parameters that are currently available

ros2 param list


then set the parameter with the desired value. (make sure it has the correct data type)

ros2 param set <node_name> <parameter_name> <value>


you can also get the current value from the parameter

ros2 param get <node_name> <parameter_name>

Link to cli tool parameter tutorial

Maybe edit your answer to include examples of get and set that the OP might find useful.
